# Building code from Jenkins using TFS

Tags: tfs, jenkins, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use Jenkins to build my code which resides in a https://*******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.

I have tried to manually check the code out using a script in jenkins e.g.

```
tf workspace /delete JENKINS /noprompt /collection:https://*******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /login:mylogin@myaccount.com,mypassword

tf workspace /new JENKINS /noprompt /collection:https://*******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /permission:Private /login:mylogin@myaccount.com,mypassword

tf workfold /workspace:JENKINS /s:https://*******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /map "$/MyProject" "%WORKSPACE%"

tf get /force /recursive
```

This runs fine from the command line but fails in Jenkins with

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access
```

Jenkins is running as Local System Account. I have tried the plugin for jenkins which no joy either. This also failed on authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have no intention of using it, I'd install and configure the TFS build controller software.  This will create the authentication link between the cloud instance and the system profile.  Jenkins, running in that user profile context, should then be able to issue TF commands and create workspaces.

That said, I'd also create a build service account and not use SYSTEM.